# Generic Method Taking A Type and Returning Instance of that Type?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a bunch of models which have the same properties - greenPeople, bluePeople, etc. For each of these, I have a controller, and in the post, I push their picture to some server and make a SQL entry describing the entry. Actually, my models are GreenPeoplePicture, BluePeoplePicture, etc.

So I have something like:

```
GreenPeoplePicture greenPeoplePicture = new GreenPeoplePicture(); 
greenPeoplePicture.Name = "blah"
greenPeoplePIcture.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

etc. Once it's filled out I stream to the remote server and then save "greenPeoplePicture" to the GreenPeoplePictures table. I want to write a generic method for this. I can't wrap my head around how to pass the type itself without passing any variable, since I want to do:

```
GreenPeoplePicture greenPeoplePicture = new GreenPeoplePicture();
```

in the method, and also have the return type be `GreenPeoplePicture`. I am sure this post is tantamount to "I can't code and don't understand generics," but I tried - at least tell me whether or not it's possible. MSDN and tutorialspoint aren't much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public T MakeColourPerson<T>() where T : new() {
    return new T();
}

var myPerson = MakeColourPerson<GreenPeoplePicture>();
```

Also, if `GreenPeoplePicture` and `BluePeoplePicture` have anything in common (for example, if they inherit from `ColourPeoplePicture`, you can change the where to be this:

`where T : ColourPeoplePicture, new()` to be more precise

This will allow you to do more useful things inside `MakeColourPerson`

```
public T MakeColourPerson<T>() 
    where T : ColourPeoplePicture, new() 
{
    var colourPerson = new T();
    colourPerson.Name = "blah";
    colourPerson.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
    return colourPerson;
}
```

Assuming `ColourPeoplePicture` exposes the properties `Name` and `Date`

Comment: I am fairly certain this is exactly what I need, thanks. Going to try to wrap my head around it fully now.  Oh, and they do all inherit from a ColourPeoplePicture equivalent. Thanks a lot, seriously.

Comment: http://stream1.gifsoup.com/view6/2583289/i-know-kung-fu-o.gif Alright, replace "kung fu" with "generics" and that's how I felt after reading that post once fully edited.

Answer (score 1):

For generics, you can use `default(T)` to initialize a variable to the default value, or you can use `new T()` to create an instance. In order to use `new()`, you should narrow the specificity of the type by adding a type constraint of `new()`

```
public T Factory<T>() where T : new() {
    return new T();
}
```

or

```
    return default(T);
```

If you want to handle the different properties of each type, then generics won't completely solve that, you'll have to supplement it with reflection to lookup properties dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, more to think about.